# Don't continue if first statement is = 0

Tags: java, oop

So I have this piece of code and I only want option 2 to be executed if option 1 has a value other than 0. If it has 0, throw an error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks! :)

```
if (option == 1){
     System.out.println("YOU HAVE SELECTED OPTION 1");
     System.out.println(accounts[i].getOwner().getfirstName() + " " +  accounts[i].getOwner().getlastName() + ", Please enter your yearly salary:");
      accounts[i].setyearlySalary(in.nextDouble());      
}
else if (option == 2){
      System.out.println("YOU HAVE SELECTED OPTION 2");
      System.out.println(accounts[i].getOwner().getfirstName() + " " +  accounts[i].getOwner().getlastName() + ", Please enter any additional salary:");

      accounts[i].setotherSalary(in.nextDouble());  

}
```

Comment: where were you stuck in doing what you said?

Comment: I tried something after option 2 if (accounts[I].setyearlySalary == 0){System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot continue if option 1 is zero.);} but it said void cannot be converted to boolean

Comment: @icewolf461 why you are using setter instead of getter in if condition
"accounts[I].setyearlySalary == 0"?

Comment: @BhushanUniyal Thanks. Changing it to get and adding a break after it solved it. gg

Comment: @icewolf461  welcome bro.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend you to create a function to set additional salary and call it for option 2 code and for case if option 1 == 0.